# Android blows up when I with the following we trying to leverage the SQLite db I created here

Tags: android, sqlite, listview, cursor, listviewitem

I get the following error when I attempt to create dynamic columns. I thought this was legit, but apparently Android and SQLite don't like this. I'm sure I'm missing something simple, but I just can't recall.

Error message is: no such column: sundayResult: , while compiling:

```
CREATE TABLE DAYSUSED(
                _id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY autoincrement, 
                sunday INTEGER NOT NULL,
                monday INTEGER NOT NULL, 
                tuesday INTEGER NOT NULL, 
                wednesday INTEGER NOT NULL, 
                thursday INTEGER NOT NULL, 
                friday INTEGER NOT NULL, 
                saturday INTEGER NOT NULL);
SELECT _id
           , volume_level
           , vibrate
           , CASE WHEN sunday = 1 THEN 'Sun' ELSE ' ' END AS sundayResult
           , CASE WHEN monday = 1 THEN 'Mon' ELSE ' ' END AS mondayResult
           , CASE WHEN tuesday = 1 THEN 'Tues' ELSE ' ' END AS tuesdayResult
           , CASE WHEN wednesday = 1 THEN 'Wed' ELSE ' ' END AS wednesdayResult
           , CASE WHEN thursday = 1 THEN 'Thur' ELSE ' ' END AS thursdayResult
           , CASE WHEN friday = 1 THEN 'Fri' ELSE ' ' END AS fridayResult
           , CASE WHEN saturday = 1 THEN 'Sat' ELSE ' ' END AS saturdayResult
           , sundayResult || ' ' || mondayResult || ' ' || tuesdayResult || ' ' || wednesdayResult || ' ' || thursdayResult || ' ' || fridayResult || ' ' || saturdayResult || ' ' AS days_of_week
 FROM DAYSUSED
```

The last line will work if I do a direct call to the actual columns like:

```
, sunday || ' ' ||
```

instead of what I have currently which is:

```
, sundayResult || ' ' ||
```

I've looked all over and don't know what else to try, as I'd really like to alter the data for the cursor.

Thanks,
Kelly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sundayResult is just an alias and you cannot use it into the same query. You need something like this. If volume_level and vibrate are coming from different table, then join it with  subquery "days"

```
SELECT _id
           , volume_level
           , vibrate
           , days.sundayResult || ' ' || days.mondayResult || ' ' || days.tuesdayResult || ' ' || days.wednesdayResult || ' ' || days.thursdayResult || ' ' || days.fridayResult || ' ' || days.saturdayResult || ' ' AS days_of_week
from
(          select
           CASE WHEN sunday = 1 THEN 'Sun' ELSE ' ' END AS sundayResult
           , CASE WHEN monday = 1 THEN 'Mon' ELSE ' ' END AS mondayResult
           , CASE WHEN tuesday = 1 THEN 'Tues' ELSE ' ' END AS tuesdayResult
           , CASE WHEN wednesday = 1 THEN 'Wed' ELSE ' ' END AS wednesdayResult
           , CASE WHEN thursday = 1 THEN 'Thur' ELSE ' ' END AS thursdayResult
           , CASE WHEN friday = 1 THEN 'Fri' ELSE ' ' END AS fridayResult
           , CASE WHEN saturday = 1 THEN 'Sat' ELSE ' ' END AS saturdayResult
           FROM DAYSUSED
) days
```

Comment: Thank you very much on the help. As i saw your solution I started thinking I might have to do a CTE or JOIN.